# selenium web driver does not open firefox with custom prefrences

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Trying to open firefox with already installed addons using selenium 2 but always opens with default firefox profile having predefined preferences

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The above lines of code initiates firefox with default profile.
How to make it initiate with user specified preferences?

Answer (score 2):

You can launch it with a custom profile using something like:

```
profile = FirefoxProfile("path.to.profile")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set profile, it could be created automatically, you just need path to addons, e.g.:

```
        string firebugPath = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox\\Profiles\\x7nutq33.default\\extensions\\firebug@software.joehewitt.com.xpi";
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();       
        profile.AddExtension(firebugPath);
        Driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```